# debug.writeline - how to get it in the debug when debugging and a file when in live

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am about to go live with a C# project, and I am struggling with a simple issue: how do I turn my `Debug.WriteLine("");` into an output file when (and only when) it is live?

What I have done: I added this to `app.config`:

```
<system.diagnostics>
   <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="textListener"
           type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="trace.log" />
      <remove name="Default" />
    </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

And then this to a `bug.log` class I use:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(msg);
}
else
{
    Trace.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

I expected it to write to the debug window if it was in a debugger (what I want) and write to an output file ('trace.log') when running live (what I want), but instead these two changes have simply placed everything in trace.log no matter what.

How do I set it up so that I get `trace.log` in a live build and a `output > debug` window in Visual Studio (Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop) if I am not running live, but using the `[ > Start]` button in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two different `.config` files for both `release` and `debug` configurations and in release configuration add a new listener to trace to a file. To manage multiple configuration files, look at the Scott Hanselman article *[Managing Multiple Configuration File Environments with Pre-Build Events](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx)*.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "Release mode" for "live" as opposed to Debug mode, how about:

```
#if DEBUG
Debug.WriteLine(msg);
#else
Trace.WriteLine(msg);
#endif
```

You can of course replace DEBUG with the actual debug constant in the precompiler.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
Debug.WriteLine(msg);
Trace.WriteLine(msg);
```

You always trace to a log. *If* a debugger is attached, you also log to the debugger window. Make sure your solution `[ > Start]` is actually attaching the debugger if you want to see the debugger output. See *[How to: Change the Start Action for Application Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/68c8335t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)*.

Comment: I think doing this plus @Hamlet Hakobyan 's idea is the way to do it :)